# Could I connect the google Cloud SQL from my PC?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have setup the GAE PHP develop environment in my local PC as this link(https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld), could I connect the GOOGLE Cloud SQL in the PHP which running on my PC?

Does the Cloud SQL requires MUST connecting from GAE living environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect via command line from the PC directly as per the below:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/commandline

Rather if you wish to connect from your DEV machine via a PHP file you must deploy that PHP file on a local webserver on your machine and it would work just the same.

To verify that it is connecting properly, go thru the steps in the link above to establish command line connectivity.

Regards